# Calculate tensorflow Metric using more than one batch at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using `tf.keras` and I have a metric that I'd like to calculate where I need multiple batches of validation data in order to calculate it reliably. Is there some way to accumulate batches before calculating the metric?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class MultibatchMetric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, num_batches, name="sdr_metric", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.num_batches = num_batches
        self.batch_accumulator = []
        self.my_metric = []

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        self.batch_accumulator.append((y_true, y_pred))
        if len(self.batch_accumulator) >= self.num_batches:
            metric = custom_multibatch_metric_func(self.batch_accumulator)
            self.my_metric.append(metric)
            self.batch_accumulator = []

    def result(self):
        return mean(self.my_metric)

    def reset_states(self):
        self.my_metric = []
        self.batch_accumulator = []
```

However, this all needs to occur on the tensorflow graph, severely complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go at your problem and it seems using the built in `add_weight` method can provide a solution. By making a state variable for a batch counter and an accumulator that has the size `(2, num_batches * batch_size, n_outputs)`. Each update a batch gets stored by adding a padded batch to the state variable and gets reset when the counter reaches the maximum number of batches. You can then get the result from the accumulator by calling your metric on the accumulator state variable. I have added an example below.

```
class Metric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, num_batches, batch_size, name="sdr_metric", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.num_batches = num_batches
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.batch_accumulator = self.add_weight(name='accumulator', shape=(2, num_batches * batch_size, 2), initializer='zeros')
        self.batch_counter = self.add_weight(name='counter', shape=(), initializer='zeros')
        
    @tf.function
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        batch_count = self.batch_counter
        batch = tf.stack([tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32), tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32)])
        paddings = [[0, 0], [batch_count * self.batch_size, (self.num_batches - batch_count - 1) * self.batch_size], [0, 0]]
        padded_batch = tf.pad(batch, paddings)
        self.batch_accumulator.assign_add(padded_batch)            
        self.batch_counter.assign_add(1)
        if batch_count == self.num_batches:
            self.reset_states()
        
    @tf.function
    def result(self):
        if self.batch_counter == self.num_batches - 1:
            return custom_multibatch_metric_func(self.batch_accumulator)
        else:
            return 0.

    def reset_states(self):
        self.batch_counter.assign(0)
        self.batch_accumulator.assign(tf.zeros((2, self.num_batches * self.batch_size, 2)))
```

And the test problem i used to verify.

```
# data
n = 1028
batch_size = 32
num_batches = 3
f = 4
lr = 10e-3

x = tf.random.uniform((n, f), -1, 1)
y = tf.concat([tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True), tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)], axis=-1)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(b, drop_remainder=True)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([Dense(f, activation='relu'), Dense(2)])
model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr), tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, metrics=Metric(num_batches, batch_size))
model.fit(ds, epochs=10)
```

Two large issues. Firstly the if statement in `result` call, but depending on what you require of the resulting metric you can return an idempotent value. Here where I assumed you just sum all the results so `0` has no effect. Secondly this approach requires you to drop the remainder unless you dataset size is divisible by your batch size.

I hope this was helpful eventhough this is not an optimal solution by any means.

Comment: This is great! I don't think you have to do that padding as you can call `assign_add` on a slice. Why is the first dimension 2? Also, why do you have that if statement in `result`? Isn't `result` only called at the end of the epoch?

Comment: The padding is a workaround because it seems you can't call assign on a slice in graph mode. I wrote this before adding the tf.function statement so that might change it and then no padding is required. The first dimension is 2 for both the true values and predicted values since `update_state` takes both `y_true` and `y_pred` as inputs. As for `result` i think you can also call this per `m` amount of steps so if you wanted this possibility you can. As i said, this is a base idea that can be tuned to your specifications. If you have more questions I would gladly assist. Hope this was helpful.